# GridView com uma linha só - Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, orientação-a-objetos, webforms, gridview

Tenho uma coluna na GridView com Horários, fiz um esquema que pega de tal hora a tal hora por exemplo: 8:00 as 8:30 e assim vai para outras linhas.
Ao todo até as 18h dá 20 linhas.
Como faço para colocar isso tudo em uma linha só ? 
Algo que quebrasse por "," e continuasse na mesma linha.
Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode mudar a sua fonte de dados, para possuir um item só ao invés de vários ou mudar de componente, escrever um table na mão talvez.

Comment: Pensei nisso de possuir um item só, mas no caso é uma lista de horários, iria ter problema de qualquer forma na hora de cortar as horas tipo, preciso fazer assim: 8:00 às 8:30, 8:30 ás 9:00 e assim vai numa linha só.

Comment: E se tu fizer um foreach e concatenar o conteúdo numa string?

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, só que tipo, vou atribuir pra string os horários que estou pegando em 2 objetos como hora_inicio e hora_fim e no final adicionar a ",". Só que ai quando acabar a lista a ultima virgula vai ficar lá ..

Comment: A última virgula você retira, isso é simples, mas a pergunta minha seria: Por que tudo numa row? Não entendi o porque, pois em row separadas fica bem mais legível, a menos que haja uma regra muito específica, por isso a pergunta, só por isso.

Comment: Uma forma de retirar a última vírgula: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1, 2, 3, ");   
 
string resultado = sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 2);

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o componente **Repeater** para fazer isso. O código similar seria:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptHorarios" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <table border="0" id="tblHorarios">
         <tr>
   </HeaderTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
        <td>Eval("Horario")</td>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FotterTemplate>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </FotterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Código:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      rptHorarios.DataSource = GetHorarios();
      rptHorarios.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Ou poderia utilizar também o DataList e setar as propriedades **RepeatDirection** e **RepeatColumn** com os respectivos valores.